# Strapi: Is there a to override plugin GraphQL schema?

Tags: graphql, strapi

I am trying to modify the GraphQL schema of the `users-permissions` plugin.

I want to change:

```
type UsersPermissionsLoginPayload {
    jwt: String!
    user: UsersPermissionsMe!
}
```

to:

```
type UsersPermissionsLoginPayload {
  isAuthenticated: Boolean!
  user: UsersPermissionsMe!
}
```

But I get  many errors when I  create `./extensions/users-permissions/config/schema.graphql.js`:

```
...

There can be only one type named "UsersPermissionsLoginInput".

Field "UsersPermissionsLoginInput.identifier" can only be defined once.

Field "UsersPermissionsLoginInput.password" can only be defined once.

Field "UsersPermissionsLoginInput.provider" can only be defined once.

There can be only one type named "UsersPermissionsLoginPayload".

Field "UsersPermissionsLoginPayload.jwt" can only be defined once.

Field "UsersPermissionsLoginPayload.user" can only be defined once.

...
```

What is the correct way to customize/extend the schema?

Edit:

I see the types can simply be extended like so:

```
module.exports = {
  definition: `
    extend type UsersPermissionsLoginPayload {
      isAuthenticated: Boolean!
   }
  `
}
```

that adds the `isAuthenticated` field to the `UsersPermissionsLoginPayload`  type  but does not remove the `jwt` field.

Is there no way to override the typedefs  and resolvers?   Do I need to implement my custom functionality using new types and new unique resolvers?